# html5: does a cache manifest share the resources of WebSql

Tags: html, memory, web-sql

I was wondering about the 50Mb maximum you can allocate for a WebSql database

```
db = openDatabase('db', '1.0', 'data', 50 * 1024 * 1024);
```

Is this 50MB only for the database, or is it shared, for example, with data from the cache manifest ?

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does various iOS versions differ in terms of webapp cache size limit & its response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605991/how-does-various-ios-versions-differ-in-terms-of-webapp-cache-size-limit-its-r)